# A function that recieves three numbers and a list, gets an average of those three numbers and subtracts the average from each number on the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a question regarding how to improve something small I wrote. I'm fairly new to Python and I tried to make this with a for loop but failed, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to write this function(I wanted to do it with a for loop but if u guys have a better idea I'd appreciate if you posted it). Thanks! 
Btw, the list recieved is only numbers, there aren't any strings, chars, etc.

```
def newList(n1,n2,n3,List):
    avg = (n1+n2+n3)/3
    i=0
    while i<len(List):
        List[i] -= avg
        i += 1
    print D
```

Comment: `List[:] = [v - avg for v in List]` should do it, without a loop.

Comment: How did your for-loop fail? "It failed" is not an adequate problem statement.

Comment: replace your `while` loop with a `for` loop- try this to see how it works `for item in List: print(item - avg)` or do as in Jean-Francois's comment if you know list comprehensions. BTW, convention says don't use capital letters for variable names

Comment: I meant that I tried to do it with a for loop but didn't manage to... like, I didn't really understand what I should do in order to complete the question with a for loop. Apologies if I didn't make myself clear enough, I'm new to the site + English isn't my first lanuage.

Comment: @Chris_Rands you helped me come up with a solution that doesn't involve  list comprehensions but involves a for loop like I originally wanted to. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python’s [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) are useful when you want to perform the same operation on every item in a list. For example, suppose you had a list of numbers defined as follows:

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To add 5 to every number in this list and put it into a variable called `new_list`, you’d use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [number + 5 for number in list_of_numbers]
```

If you check the value of `new_list`, you’ll see it is:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You can use a list comprehension in your `newList()` method:

```
def newList(n1, n2, n3, list):
  average = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3
  result_list = [item - average for item in list]
  return result_list
```

When you call it like so:

```
newList(1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6])
```

you’ll get this result:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

use comprehensive list such as :

```
def newList(n1,n2,n3,List):
    avg = (n1+n2+n3)/3
    print [i-avg for i in List]
```

To explain List comprehension using this example :

- let's explain 'for i in List'

  - It's a For loop meaning, for each element of 'List' where 'i' will be 
    equal to this element.

    List = [1,2,3]
    First loop : i = 1, Second loop i=2 and third loop i=3
  - then part 'i-avg' means for each loop, return value of i-avg
    Let say 'avg = 1'
    Fist loop : (i=1) 1-1 (i-avg) is returned; 0
    Second loop : (i=2) 2-1 is returned; 1
    Third loop : (i=3) 3-1 is returned;2

Comment: I don't know  list comprehensions yet but thank you!

Comment: Tried to explain in my answer

Comment: With this explanation and the other answer I think I understand list comprehensions pretty well now, thank you!

Comment: oh and I was wondering, why did you use print in the function?

Comment: As an example, if you want to store in a list you can append it or something else, print has no purpose except for demonstration